# how Localbitcoins and other bitcoin wallet able to send/receive without network fee

Tags: bitcoin

I have been exploring bitcoin API and I found there is network fee for every transaction which is around 0.0001 but I noticed many trading and bitcoin related agencies doesn't charge any network fee at all for transfer between user on same Website/App. Few of which are cryptopia, Zebpay and localbitcoins.

Could someone help me understand that how they are able to transfer between wallet without any network fee.

Comment: You should really ask this on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organizations that offer online wallets aren't obligated to handle transactions using the actual Bitcoin blockchain; they may instead choose to keep their own off-chain record of transactions between users. While faster and cheaper than on-chain transactions, this system is often less secure, especially since the transaction records are centralized.

Only when a user transfers Bitcoins between an external wallet would an organization utilize the blockchain; this is when a transfer would cost some network fee and take some time to process.

Comment: That make complete sense but what about the wallet address user has provided.

Comment: @HiteshChandwani If a user is transferring within the same application, then the wallet address would only be used to link transactions to an organization's off-chain accounts. The actual wallet address on the blockchain won't see the transaction. You can use a [blockchain explorer](https://blockchain.info/) to check whether a transaction was actually performed through the blockchain; with that, you'd be able to see how transactions within some applications don't actually modify anything on the blockchain.